# How to update component in react native with a store redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm making an app in react-native and I use a store redux to manage the player, each player has an id and a name. So I have already made action to add and set the player, and all work fine, when I had a player, the component is updated and the same for the setPlayer. Now I want to make an action for the delete, but when I pressed the button to delete the component is nos updated, but I'm sure that the player is delete in the background.

Here the code ( component for the player )

---

```
import React from 'react'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons' // Pour ajouter la corbeille
import { vw, vh } from 'react-native-viewport-units-fix' 
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const heightPlayer = 8*vh;
const sizeIcon     = 12*vw;


class JoueurListe extends React.Component {

    _listItems() {
        return (
            
            this.props.tabJoueur.map((joueur) =>
                <View 
                    style={styles.container_player}
                    key={joueur.id}>          
                    <TextInput
                        style={[this.props.style, styles.player]}
                        maxLength={12}
                        placeholder={joueur.player_name}
                        placeholderTextColor='#446C85'
                        onChangeText={(text) => this._setPlayer(text, joueur.id)}
                        />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._delPlayer(joueur.id)}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons
                            name={"delete"}
                            size ={sizeIcon}
                            style={styles.delete}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View> )
        )
    }

    _delPlayer(index) {
        const action = { type:'DEL_PLAYER', index: index}
        this.props.dispatch(action)

    }

    _setPlayer(text, index) {
        let action;
        if ( text === "") action = { type: "SET_PLAYER", player_name: "Joueur "+ index, index: index }
        else              action = { type: "SET_PLAYER", player_name: text, index: index }

        this.props.dispatch(action)
    }

    _showPlayer() {
        return (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', width: '100%'}}>
                {this._listItems()}
            </View>
        )
    }

    _addPlayer() {
        const action = { type: "ADD_PLAYER", player_name: "Joueur " }
        this.props.dispatch(action)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.main_container}>
                {this._showPlayer()}
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container_player} onPress={() => this._addPlayer()}>
                    <Ionicons name="add-circle" size={sizeIcon}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main_container: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        width: '100%',
        top: '15%',
        marginLeft: 25*vw,
        marginBottom: 20*vh
    },
    container_player: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: heightPlayer,
        borderRadius: 15,
        borderColor: '#BFB9B9',
        borderWidth: 2,
        textAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginBottom: '4%',
        width: '75%',
        paddingLeft: 2*vw,
        paddingRight: 2*vw
    },
    player: {
        left: '0%',
        color: '#446C85',
        fontSize: 20,
        width: '75%'
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
    delete: {
        right: '0%'
    }
    
})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state
  }
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(JoueurListe)
```

---

And the stor

---

```
let idJoueur = 1;

const initialState = {
    tabJoueur: [{id: 1, player_name: "Joueur 1"}]
}

function reducerPlayer(state = initialState, action) {
    let nextState = state

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_PLAYER':
            return nextState = {
                tabJoueur: [...state.tabJoueur, { id: ++idJoueur , player_name: action.player_name + idJoueur } ]                
            }
        case 'SET_PLAYER':
            nextState.tabJoueur[action.index-1] = {id: action.index, player_name: action.player_name }
            return nextState
        case 'DEL_PLAYER':
            if (idJoueur > 1) {
                nextState.tabJoueur.splice(action.index-1, 1)
                for (let i=action.index-1;i<nextState.tabJoueur.length;i++){
                    let tmp = nextState.tabJoueur[i].player_name
                    if ( tmp.includes("Joueur ") )tmp="Joueur " + (i+1)
                    nextState.tabJoueur[i] = { id: i+1, player_name: tmp}
                }

                console.log(nextState.tabJoueur)

                idJoueur--
            }
            return nextState
        default:
            return nextState
    }
    
}

export default reducerPlayer
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your component is already right, your reducer is not.

You are still modifying the original object there - just because you do `let nextState = state` does not mean that `nextState` is a new state. It actually is just a pointer to the original state, so you are still modifying that.

As all this immutable logic can get quite complicated I would recommend you to check out the official Redux Toolkit which allows you to actually write "mutating" code in their reducers that ends up in an immutable copy automatically: [modern redux with redux toolkit (from the official redux tutorials)](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux)

Comment: I don't understand why I need to do that, when I show the state in my console, it is right and it's not nextState but state, so what do you want from me with this toolkit?

Comment: Yes, the "new state" is updated. So is the old state. Because both are the same object. You never explicitly create a new object as new state, you just continue using the old object.
And yes, you can validate that the state has the shape you want afterwards, but that doesn't mean that react-redux is able to detect that a change has occured - because you did that modification in a way that react-redux cannot detect.

So either you need to write "immutable logic" by hand, or use the official recommendation by the redux team: redux toolkit. Because that does that for you.

Comment: If you want to do it the old way, read through https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns - but you will do a LOT more work than necessary nowadays when following those outdated patterns.

Comment: Maybe also this example will help you understand the concept - just try executing this on your own - the following code will modify `oldState`:

`const oldState = { something: "old" };
const newState = oldState;
newState.something = "new";
console.log(oldState)`

Comment: Hello phry, sorry if I didn't answer you earlier. I had some exams and I couldn't work on my personal project. Thanks a lot for your advice, I tried your code and if I have correctly understood. The two objects are the same, new is not a copy of the old but is the new object who's referencing the first (maybe like a pointer in C ??)
So I will check your website to understand, thanks a lot